# How do you query a timestamp field in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

## Question

**How do you execute a query that filters based on a timestamp field in firebase?**

Equivalently, what must I fill the `...` in:

```js
const q = query(ref, where("time", "<", ...));
```

so as to filter by a the current date (for example)?

- `Timestamp.now()` (Timestamp object)?
- `new Date()` (Date object)?
- `Date.now()` (Time in milliseconds)?
- `Math.round(Date.now()/1000)` (Time in seconds)?

## More Context

I am trying to make a collection query based on the timestamp field of the documents.
i.e.

```js
where("next_spaced_revise", "<", ...)
```

I am using react-hooks-firebase, so make this query via:

```js
const [values, loading, error] = useCollectionData(q);
```

I am getting a very erroneous behaviour that I am struggling to debug. What happens is that the react component (which the above hook is in) keeps on getting mounted and unmounted. When I place a console.log within preamble code of the JSX component, it gets called over and over.

This behaviour also happens when I don't use react-hooks-firebase and instead use the promises of vanilla firebase `getDocs`

I have found one error message, which seems to reflect the mentioned behaviour of mounting and unmounting:

> Error message Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render

After more investigation, I believe this behaviour occurs whenever an incorrectly constructed query is made. **Hence, why I believe that this boils down to getting the correct term to fill `...` in `where("next_spaced_revise", "<", ...)`**

[image: Image of Example doc]
Please note that what I called "time" in my example corresponds to "next_spaced_revise"

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your Firestore document? If you are storing Firestore timestamp then you can use the same to query, if you are storing Time in ms as number then use that in where

Comment: You can pass in either a `Date` object (your second code snippet) or a `Timestamp` object. If you pass in a `Date`, what isn't working?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen If I pass either in, I get the mentioned behaviour of constantly unmounting and mounting the react objects.

Comment: Interestingly, this error continues  even if nothing later uses ```values```. It must just be a problem with the query